# How to install programs from snap older version

Tags: 18.04, sublime-text, snap-store

04 32 bit I have problem that I cannot install Sublime text , i tried diffrent ways but it dosent install ,i want to install Sublime text 3 . I tried :

1. Installing it from snap
   But there is only 64 bit and arm not 32 bit
2. Downloading from offical website
   I downloaded tar.gz2 file but i don't know how to install it (./configure is not working, showing error `No directory or file`)and i runs cuz it has direct executable but i want to install it
3. Ubuntu software store 
   I cannot find it there;
4. From offical repositery(ies)
   I tried methods from `itsfoss.com` and `linuxize.com` but didnt work

I remember it i some how install it from snap only but i didn't work (but that time version 3 was stable , so is there any way I can install older version from snap or any other way for 32 bit pc

Comment: Support for 32 bit systems is disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text 3 32-bit is available on the official site here: https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3211_x32.tar.bz2 . You should just unpack the archive somewhere (it will create a subdirectory called `sublime_text_3`) and then run the executable file `sublime_text` from that subdirectory. It should work.

There is a file `sublime_text.desktop` in that subdirectory that you can use to integrate the app into your applications menu (if this is what you mean by installing). This file "as is" (if you don't edit it) assumes that the application has been unpacked to `/opt/sublime_text` directory, so you should either unpack it there or change path in the .desktop file. Then, copy the `sublime_text.desktop` file into `/usr/share/applications/` directory and the application should appear in your menu. You can find more information about .desktop files here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Man i tried that but it just crashes and if i run from downloads it won't be installing and not so cool